# Debug assertion failed using float variable and scanf() to get user grades and printf() them

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float grade1 = 0.0;
    float grade2 = 0.0;
    float grade3 = 0.0;

    printf("Enter your three test grades in decimal form: \n");

    scanf(" %f", grade1);
    scanf(" %f", grade2);
    scanf(" %f", grade3);

    float avg = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
    printf("Average: %.2f \n", avg);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am using a tutorial on the new boston YT channel and this code does not work on my compiler while tutorial code does work. I have Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: Turn on _all_ compiler warnings: `float grade1 = 0.0; ... scanf(" %f", grade1);` should warn about type mis-match.  `float` vs `float*`.

Comment: ... does the tutorial *really* omit the `&`s?

Comment: ... the Boston YT channel tutorial I found about `scanf` describes string input, where the `&` is not present, because the array decays to the pointer required. Youtube tutorials might be bettered by one of [these sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide code could not be the same, it would not work.
I suggest you to enable the warnings in your compiler, which will save you from really trivial mistakes in the future.

So, the error is here:

```
scanf(" %f", grade1);
scanf(" %f", grade2);
scanf(" %f", grade3);
```

The three variables need `&` operator to receive the value.

```
scanf(" %f", &grade1);
scanf(" %f", &grade2);
scanf(" %f", &grade3);
```

I would recommend you to have a look at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Answer (score 1):

You should scan the address of the float, etc

```
scanf( " %f", &grade1);
```